# Convergent sequence definition

Tags: real-analysis

(A sequence $(a_n)$ *does not* converge to the limit $a$) $\Leftrightarrow$ (there exists a number $\epsilon>0$ such that there is an infinite number of terms of $(a_n)$ such that $|a_n-a|\geq\epsilon$).

Firstly, the direction $(\Leftarrow)$ is proved using the definition of the convergent sequence.

Now, about the direction $(\Rightarrow)$, some informal thoughts are: The sequence $(a_n)$ converges to the limit $a$ if for every $\epsilon>0$, there exist some final terms of $(a_n)$ that belong to $(a-\epsilon,a+\epsilon)$. So, $(a_n)$ does not converge to the limit $a$ if $(a_m,a_{m+1},\ldots)$ for every $m\in\mathbb{N}$ has at least one term $(a_i),i\geq m$ that doesn't belong to $(a-\epsilon,a+\epsilon)$. My question is: is this formal enough? can we conclude that the number of $(a_i),i\geq m$ is infinite using the previous statement? How can I formally justify it?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that given $\epsilon$ there exists only finitely many $a_n$ such that $|a_n-a|\ge \epsilon.$ Let $N$ denote the biggest of the index satisfying previous inequality. Then:

$$n>N\implies |a_n-a|<\epsilon.$$ But, this would mean that $(a_n)$ converges to $a.$ So the number of $a_n$'s must be infinite.